# Elementos reutilizáveis na Metodologia CSS BEM

Tags: css, front-end, bem

Estou estudando sobre a metodologia BEM (bem no começo, assumo), e fiquei em dúvida sobre um aspecto da mesma. Vejo que ela visa padronizar os meios de declaração do CSS de sua página através dos conceitos de blocos, elementos e modificadores, mas uma dúvida me surgiu.

Digamos que possuo uma página com estrutura simples (para efeito de exemplo), dividida em quatro seções: **Header**, **sidebar**, **content** e **footer**. Imagine que, por algum motivo, todas as seções possuam campos **Input** com objetivos diferentes (number, text, password), mas que receberão o mesmo padrão CSS (fonte, cor da fonte, texto centralizado, etc). Pelo que entendi, a declaração seria, **por** **exemplo**, a seguinte:

```
.header__inputLogin {}
.header__inputPassword {}
.sidebar_inputSearch {}
.content__inputNumber {}
.footer__inputContato {}
```

(Aliás, utilizando esse padrão, escrever as classes como o nome separado por um hífen ao invés de letra maíuscula poderia gerar confusão com um **modificador**? Exemplo: **.header__input-login**)

Mas se todos os elementos vão possuir exatamente as mesmas propriedades CSS, poderia declarar somente **input {}** ou, então, **.input-algumNome {}** , a fim de reduzir a redundância de código e melhorar a manutenabilidade? Além disso, é recomendado utilizar os @extends do SASS em modificadores com o mesmo objetivo (reduzir redundância do código)?

Obrigado!

Comment: Esse [post](https://willianjusten.com.br/falando-sobre-rscss/#tentando) ajuda?

Comment: Hmm, achei a metodologia consideravelmente mais limpa e prática. Obrigado pela dica!

Answer (score -1):

Como a resposta do Luiz Felipe, que sugeriu [RSCSS](https://willianjusten.com.br/falando-sobre-rscss/#tentando), você pode considerar seu Input como um componente individual, um "bloco". Desta forma, você administra esses componentes com uma organização mais clara.

Nesse barco, talvez caiba falar de metodologias como o [Atomic Design](https://bradfrost.com/blog/post/atomic-web-design/), que versa a respeito dessa divisão "celular", organizando seu sistema a partir de partes menores reutilizáveis.